# Join table based on the last hit in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am using Power BI and need to join two tables, but I want to display only the last result. Below I show more details:

Table1:

```
number  description
263745  Bank reconciliation
```

Table2:

```
number  status
263745  progress
263745  completed
```

After joining the tables, the result:

```
number  description         status
263745  Bank reconciliation progress
263745  Bank reconciliation completed
```

But I would like to show only the last result, as below:

```
number  description         status
263745  Bank reconciliation completed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add an index column to your Table2
2. Create a calculated column in Table1 like this:

`Last Status = LOOKUPVALUE(Table2[status], Table2[number], Table1[number], Table2[id], CALCULATE(MAX(Table2[id]), FILTER(Table2, Table1[number] = Table2[number])))`

If you do not have an index column but a date column, simply change the CALCULATE(MAX(...) condition to not get the max id but max date.

3. If you like, hide the Table2